# Counting affected rows using Groovy SQL

Tags: sql, groovy, sql-insert, sql-delete

Suppose I have the following SQL table definition:

```
create table test(
    id number(5) primary key
);
```

Furthermore, I'd like to execute `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements on said table by using Groovy's SQL support.

Given the following code, which executes an `INSERT` statement:

```
Sql db = new Sql(some_dataSource)
String query = "insert into test (id) values (999)"
def result = db.execute(query)
```

- Can I know, inside this code, how many rows were inserted into `test` (in this case, 1)?
- Is the `result` variable useful in determining this?

I've tried looking at Groovy's SQL support documentation [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+6+-+Groovy+SQL) and [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Database+features), but the examples provided only seem to count rows over `SELECT` statements.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that syntax for inserting multiple rows is incorrect.  Usually that would insert one row with 4 columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the number of rows inserted with [`Sql.getUpdateCount()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#getUpdateCount%28%29).  Example:

```
db.execute(query)
println db.updateCount
```

The return value from execute is a boolean indicating whether the statement was successfully executed.

The API docs for [`Sql.execute()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#execute%28groovy.lang.GString%29) have a complete explanation.

Comment: ... sigh... *head desk* I guess I should just volunteer to update the Codehaus docs with this example, which I'm sure is very typical amongst newcomers. Thank you!